# Windows 7: The ARP entry addition failed: Access is denied

Tags: windows-7, arp

I'm on Windows 7 and am trying to assign a static arp entry for my default gateway using the command:

```
arp -s 172.24.7.254 00-05-01-f9-28-00 172.24.1.20
```

But I get the following error:

```
The ARP entry addition failed: Access is denied.
```

When I don't mention my ip-address at the end, the static ip gets assigned for the virtual interface created automatically for virtualbox. I'm using an elevated prompt. I'll be grateful for suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Still an issue on Windows 10.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here is what I found and it works great

[arp -s : access denied. On the default gateway](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/063cfe1a-d347-42af-9d41-7962e758de24/arp-s-access-denied-on-the-default-gateway?forum=w7itpronetworking)

Here is what I used :

delete:

```
netsh interface ip delete neighbors "Network card name here" "Gateway.IP.goes.here"
```

Add:

```
netsh interface ip add neighbors "Network card name here" "Gateway.IP.goes.here" "MAC-address-of-gateway-with-dash-here"
```

good luck

Comment: If anybody is wondering what "Network card name here" means, it was "Local Area Connection" for me.

Comment: Use the command `netsh interface show interface` to get a list of valid interfaces (network card names).

Comment: For me it was "Ethernet".

Answer (score 22):

To set arp static in windows 7 64bit you must use netsh comand as follow

enter this command

```
netsh interface ipv4 add neighbors "Local Area Connection" inetaddr MAC
```

For Example

```
netsh interface ipv4 add neighbors "Local Area Connection" 192.168.0.1 00-24-01-d2-3a-bd
```

(If you are using a wireless rather than a LAN cable connection, use "Wireless Network Connection" instead.)