# Force an IP to a MAC on virtual network (using netsh wlan command)

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I'm creating as virtual network on my PC using netsh wlan commands and it's working great. However, at this point a need came to me to force a particular IP to a MAC address. Ofcourse it will be an IP that is allowed. All I need is to force a connecting device (with a static MAC) to have the same IP every time they connect to my virtual network.

Is this doable?

Comment: IP addresses are usually assigned by DHCP, or set statically on the device itself. You would need to reserve the IP for that mac on a dhcp server if one is running, otherwise you could just set the IP address for that device to static.

Comment: I would preffer (if possible) to assign the IP on the host, rather than try to force it by the connecting device. So that's my question, if I can do it with microsoft's netsh wlan terminology (sorry not a particular expert of the networking).

Comment: Usage netsh interface ip add neighbors "Network card name here" "Gateway.IP.goes.here" "MAC-address-of-gateway-with-dash-here"               from   http://superuser.com/questions/101293/windows-7-the-arp-entry-addition-failed-access-is-denied